# Can not create SFTP user Debian 7

Tags: debian, sftp, useradd

I have a linode and I access via ssh throw terminal.
I need to create an sftp user which his default directory (and the only he can access) is `/var/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/directory`

Now, I did it, but when I try to connect I get broken pipe or connection rejected by peer

What I did is this:

```
$ adduser --home /var/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/directory/ username
$ chown username:username /var/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/directory/
$ chmod 755 /var/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/directory/
$ nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I added the following lines

```
Match User username
   ChrootDirectory /var/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/directory/
   AllowTCPForwarding no
   X11Forwarding no
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is the actual error

[image]

EDIT2: this is the error in filezilla

[image]

EDIT 3: auth.log

```
 Oct 15 17:47:11 (none) sshd[361]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/www/xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/public_html/extras_html"
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us the actual error you get.

Comment: Ok, i did it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was because I did this:

```
$ chown user:user /var/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/directory/
```

What I had to do is this:

```
$chown root:root /var/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/directory/
```

Then, inside "directory" I made a directory for the user with 777 permission (is not the better way but it works).

The "rejected by peer" error is because /directory must have 755 permission.

Answer (score 3):

This was answered many times, but I can't find it now. The answer is RTFM.

Short story long: From `man sshd_config` you can get this line:

> **ChrootDirectory**
>
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  **All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.**  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

Which provides explanation for your error message. Fixing the ACLs on the path will solve your issue.

Comment: You should mention [CVE-2009-2904](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-2904) and/or [this email message](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2010-January/028151.html) to explain why that restriction exists.

Comment: @derobert Yes, thanks for mentioning it. But this is the long story much longer :)